# iOS Enterprise OTA - Is there a way to output plist from php?

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise, ota

I want to use php to output plist that is in item-service link.

Like this
**itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=xxxxxx.php?id=xxx**
(In php file, output plist string from app data in db)

Is it possible?
If it is possible, please show me example code in php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plist file is just a specially formed XML file.  This is something you could generate in any language.  Examples for PHP XML output can be found in other questions such as this one: [How to output XML string from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717302/how-to-output-xml-string-from-php/5717344#5717344)